# Wrong time of photo on Nexus 4

Tags: nexus-4, photos, time-zones

After I took a photo with my Nexus 4, I clicked "Details" and found out the taken day and time are wrong. Such as, it should be "Feb 25, 2015 6:50PM", but it shows "Feb 26, 2015 12:50:13AM". How should I fix it?

Comment: Depending on your timezone, this is probably UTC time. Check the Camera settings for contextual filename, and see if it allows you to change the styling of the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I was having that problem until I turned on *Save Location*, then the time stamp became exactly the right time.